First Element is Undefined in Drop Event Handler using jQuery UI Draggable and Droppable
I'm working on a web application (via python Flask server) using jQuery UI's draggable and droppable features. I have draggable elements that are supposed to be combined when dropped into a droppable area. However, I'm encountering an issue where the firstElement variable is undefined in the drop event handler.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Element Combination Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="elements-container">
        <div class="draggable" id="air" draggable="true">Air</div>
        <div class="draggable" id="earth" draggable="true">Earth</div>
        <div class="draggable" id="fire" draggable="true">Fire</div>
        <div class="draggable" id="water" draggable="true">Water</div>
    </div>
    <div id="game-area">
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        let firstElement = null;

        $(".draggable").draggable({
            helper: "clone",
            start: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).css("opacity", "0.5");
            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).css("opacity", "1");
            }
        });

        $("#game-area").droppable({
            accept: ".draggable",
            hoverClass: "dragover",
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                const droppedElement = ui.helper.attr('id');
                console.log("Dropped element ID:", droppedElement); // Debug log

                if (!droppedElement) {
                    console.error("Dropped element has no ID");
                    return;
                }

                if (firstElement) {
                    const element1 = firstElement;
                    const element2 = droppedElement;
                    console.log("Combining elements:", element1, element2); // Debug log

                    // Perform AJAX call here
                    // $.ajax({ ... });

                    firstElement = null;
                } else {
                    firstElement = droppedElement;
                    $("#result").text(`First element selected: ${firstElement}`);
                    console.log("First element set to:", firstElement); // Debug log
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Issue:
When I drag and drop elements, the firstElement variable appears as undefined. I’ve verified that the IDs are correctly set in the HTML and the jQuery UI draggable and droppable settings seem correct.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
Checked HTML IDs for consistency.
Verified that firstElement is set correctly in the drop handler.
Added debug logs to inspect variable values.
Why is firstElement undefined, and how can I resolve this issue?
If it has anything to do with the AI API I'm using or python I'll give the python code.

In your code, firstElement is being set correctly in the drop event, but when you drop an element, the ui.helper may not have the expected id. Make sure the id attribute is set properly in the HTML and that ui.helper has it when dropped.
To fix it, you should check if the ui.helper is correctly grabbing the id:
const droppedElement = ui.helper.attr('id'); 

Ensure that when you set firstElement, it has the expected ID:
firstElement = droppedElement; 

So, verify that IDs are correctly set and used when elements are dragged and dropped.
